# In Hoist does Hoist.data().save(obj) overwrite the object or merge it?

Tags: hoist

When I save an object into Hoist data when there is an existing `_id` does it merge the object or overwrite it?

For example:

`Hoist.data("FOO").findById("a")`

returns

`{ _id: "a", hash: "moose", prop2: "asda" }`

after

`Hoist.data("FOO").save( { _id: "a", hash: "moo" })`

is the result going to be

`{ _id: "a", hash: "moo" }` or `{ _id: "a", hash: "moo", prop2: "asda" }`

Answer (score 2):

It performs a merge on the existing object with the new object.

So the result will be `{ _id: "a", hash: "moo", prop2: "asda" }`